# How not to resolve all users with tilde and tab completion in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

To go in some subfolder of my home folder I type `cd ~/sub[tab]`. This is completed to `cd ~/subfolder`. Everything is fine.

If I accidently forget the slash and type `cd ~sub[tab]` all users are being resolved a a match is searched for. This takes some time, since in our company we have a central user server and a lot of users.

Can I turn the resolving of all users off, but still work with the tilde `~` ?

I use bash version 4.3.0.

I never need to go into some users home via `cd ~someUser`.

Comment: Tilde-Expansion is a shell feature. I don't know if you can partially disable it but I guess it will depend on your shell

Comment: @gogaz I edited my question to specify the bash version I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and find the function `tilde()` (around line 941). Here, just comment out the line number `946`. Finally, the function should look as below:

```
# Perform tilde (~) completion
# @return  True (0) if completion needs further processing,
#          False (> 0) if tilde is followed by a valid username, completions
#          are put in COMPREPLY and no further processing is necessary.
_tilde()
{
    local result=0
    if [[ $1 == \~* && $1 != */* ]]; then
        # Try generate ~username completions
        #COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -P '~' -u "${1#\~}" ) )
        result=${#COMPREPLY[@]}
        # 2>/dev/null for direct invocation, e.g. in the _tilde unit test
        [[ $result -gt 0 ]] && compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
    fi
    return $result
}
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Isn't it better to redefine the function to always return `0`, eliminating the possibility of returning the length of a previous set of options?